# Is there a way to build snapcraft parts in parallel

Tags: snapcraft

I use snapcraft to build sources. Faced with problem that cpu is not heavy loaded during build of snapcraft due to single threaded mode in snapcraft. It runs pull for one part, then for the second one, then the third one, etc. After pull is done in single threaded mode it starts build of only one part, then second part, etc. The same for pull and stage. Then stage and prime. The problem is that 70-80% of time cpu is not using all its cores. It uses all cores only during build of few parts, because it has a lot of sources and it is build.

It there any way to force snapcraft to run pull/build/stage/prime for all parts in the same time. So snapcraft will trigger build for few parts at the same time, instead of single threaded one after the other.